# gpedit.msc doesn't work on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, gpedit

I have installed Windows 7 64-bit on my laptop. I tried the command

> gpedit.msc

but the window doesn't appear. Is there any reason for this or can I fix this?

Comment: What edition of windows do you have, not all versions come with it.

Comment: Hi @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the respone. My windows edition is windows 7 home premium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has included the Policy Editor only in the Enterprise and Ultimate versions of Windows 7.

**Method One:**
 You may try running an SFC scan in an elevated command prompt:
 
 1. Type *cmd* in your start menu
 2. Right click on *cmd.exe* and select *Run as Administrator*
 3. In the command shell type out:

> SFC /scannow

For more information on the SFC command try [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)

**Method Two:**
You may try creating a new administrator account and trying to run the tool from there.

However, my guess is that you're using one of the more basic Microsoft Windows versions, one that doesn't allow **Gpedit.msc** and the tool isn't available for you.

---

There may be an alternative method, if you are using Windows Home Basic, you may try [this](http://thecustomizewindows.com/2011/07/group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-enable/) - however, note that this is a third party tool. I personally wouldn't recommend it, but if you would like to try it, go ahead. It does look rather shady though. :/

Answer (score 5):

Gpedit.msc is not included with Windows 7 or Vista Home Premium. It's only available in Windows 7/Vista Business, **Ultimate** and **Enterprise editions**.

This article([**`Askvg`**](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions/)) shows how to enable this feature.

Comment: The link is dead.